# How to assign array values into object as key values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm getting a request in the following form:

```
req = {
"id": ["1","2"],
"values": ["fruit", "vegies"]
}
```

I want to send response as the following:

```
res = {
"idMap": {
    "1": ["fruit", "veggies"],
    "2": ["fruit", "veggies"]
}
}
```

I tried using map function but values comes as **[Array]** and not as **["fruits", "veggies"]**. I attach the code below:

```
const values = req.values
const id = req.id.map((ids) => {
    const idmap = {
        [ids]: values
    }
    return idmap;
});
req = {
    "idMap": id
}
```

help me with this guys. Thanks in advance..

Comment: should `res` have the same object reference of the arrays?

Comment: Your code seems to be working in my console actually.

Comment: Maybe you also need to JSON.stringify() in your console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `reduce` for making an object - `map` returns an array.

```js
const req = {
  "id": ["1", "2"],
  "values": ["fruit", "vegies"]
};

const res = {
  idMap: req.id.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[c] = [...req.values], a), {})
};

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You could also loop through the array and assign properties of a result object:

```js
const req = {
  "id": ["1", "2"],
  "values": ["fruit", "vegies"]
};

let res = {
  idMap: {}
};

let values = req.values;
req.id.forEach((id, index) => res.idMap[id] = [...values]);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: i want response as {"1": ["fruits","veggies"], "2": ["fruits","veggies"]}

Comment: Oh, I see - my bad @New_Coder.

Comment: Fixed @New_Coder - any better?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate an object from the mapped entries with (upcoming) [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var req = { id: ["1", "2"], values: ["fruit", "vegies"] },
    res = { idMap: Object.fromEntries(req.id.map(k => [k, req.values])) };

console.log(res);
```